# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached (python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium to access a page. I'm able to access the elements on the main page, but once I go to the next page selenium keeps throwing this error. My code is very simple:

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("website")
#switch to main frame -->
driver.switch_to.frame("fraDefault") 
#login, switch to next page

This part all works. The next part doesn't:

#next page --> 
driver.switch_to.frame("panMenu_Frame")

This is where it keeps throwing the error. 
My chromedriver version is 102.0.5005.61 
chrome version is 102.0.5005.115

I've tried adding WebDriverWait, that didn't work, I've tried switching to parentframe, didn't work either. Can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a problem specifice tor Chromedriver. Switch to geckodriver (firefox) and this problem will go away.

Comment: Oh awsome, that works :)

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you! Happy coding :)